# Any difference between kernel32.dll Sleep and Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, wait, kernel32

Is there any difference(performance, implementation. .whatever) between the following:

i)

```
DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public extern static void Sleep(uint msec);
```

..then call Sleep function

ii)

```
Thread.Sleep()
```

Comment: The obvious difference is that one is designed to be used in native code, the other in managed code targeting the .NET Framework. Can you explain what you want to know *beyond* that distinction?

Comment: Do we need to consider about using the alternative form, or both will server the purpose?

Comment: No, there's no reason you should ever have to P/Invoke `Sleep` from kernel32.dll when you're writing C# code. `Thread.Sleep` will do just fine, and is the preferred method.

Comment: Ehh... You are concerned about the performance of _Sleep_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference, actually.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/17/51361.aspx) explains why managed threads should never do unmanaged blocking, if possible. The [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx) has the same guideline without all the underlying details.

P.S. [`Thread.Sleep` is a sign of a poorly-designed program](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

Comment: Agreed. Why you would *want* to do unmanaged blocking of managed threads is, of course, beyond me.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't think so.  They both work on the current thread only.

Take care though when using the Sleep function in the main thread as programs that depend on synchronized timing usually cause problems when external configurations change.

Using Sleep in support or listening threads is usually not a problem though.